# dnscrypt-proxy - not getting dnssec results

Tags: dnssec, dnscrypt

I have installed dnscrypt-proxy and am using and dnssec enabled provider; however, when testing my configuration, I'm not getting back dnssec information:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5300 weather.com +dnssec +multi


; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P3 <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 5300 weather.com +dnssec +multi
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 256
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;weather.com.       IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
weather.com.        20 IN A 23.199.61.218

;; Query time: 112 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5300(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 07 10:27:54 EST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`weather.com` is not a signed zone. Authoritative servers don't serve any DNSSEC-related information, so none is returned by the resolvers either.

In order to check that the resolver properly supports DNSSEC, try resolving a different name. The root zone is obviously signed, and will return DNSSEC records. Or you can try resolving the `dnscrypt.org` name.

Comment: Okay, so basically I cannot require DNSSEC because not all zones are signed.